# How do openstack API services communicate with other services?

Tags: openstack

Every major service in OpenStack has an API service as endpoint for clients to access, eg. openstack-nova-api, openstack-glance-api etc. But for every major service, there are other minor services like openstack-nova-scheduler, openstack-nova-conductor etc. these services are suggested to be deployed on other nodes rather the node where API service is running to get some kind of isolation.
My question is how openstack-nova-api knows where the real services(openstack-nova-scheduler/openstack-nova-conductor) are running, how they communicate with other? When openstack-nova-api got a new request, how does it distribute it to the real services which can process and send back the results?

Answer (score 2):

Internal communication between OpenStack modules is done through the AMQP message queue, typically managed by RabbitMQ.